# (Python) Editing tables in a SQL DB?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I'm attempting to edit an sql database using python. The following code works:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("INSERT INTO Tablename (column1, column2) VALUES ( ?, ? )",
( value1, value2 ) )
conn.commit()

cur.close()
```

However, if I wish to edit a different table, and its columns are 'When' and 'What' I cant edit the table?

```
OperationalError: near "When": syntax error
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer myself!

Just put brackets around column names that have SQL keywords. In my problem I just had to change the column name from 'when' to '[when]'.

**INSTEAD OF**

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Tablename (When, What) VALUES ( ?, ? )",
( value1, value2 ) )
```

**USE**

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Tablename ([When], What) VALUES ( ?, ? )",
( value1, value2 ) )
```